# Delete files older than X minutes

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I would like to delete files that are older than 59 minutes. I have this so far:

```
find /tmp -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This doesn't work and seems to delete all files. I've tested this several times and I think the issue is to do with `daystart`.

I've read the man page and it seems to base time on the beginning of the day rather than from 24 hours ago. If this is the case how can I accurately delete files that are older than 59 minutes? Do I need to account for `daystart` and add some more minutes?

Example:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-138-30-118:/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root   4096 Jul 20 14:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root   4096 Jun 25 18:34 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Jul 20 12:35 a.txt
```

Both the following commands, return the file:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-138-30-118:/tmp$ find /tmp -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.*"
/tmp/a.txt
```

And:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-138-30-118:/tmp$ find /tmp -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +359 -type f -name "*.*"
/tmp/a.txt
```

However, the file is not older than 659 minutes (10.9 hours)! But at 759 (12.65 hours), it doesn't return the file anymore?

Comment: By the way. I like the parameter `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When used with `-mmin`, `-daystart` appears to make it calculate from the *end* of today, not the beginning.

If you just want to find files modified more than 59 minutes ago, you don't need that option. `-mmin` calculates from the current time by default.

```
barmar@dev:~/testdir$ date
Sat Jul 20 10:02:20 CDT 2013
barmar@dev:~/testdir$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 barmar adm 0 Jul 20 09:57 a.txt
barmar@dev:~/testdir$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +2 -type f
./a.txt
barmar@dev:~/testdir$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +10 -type f
```

Comment: Hey @Barmar, you saved my time buddy thumbs up.

Comment: Hey @folks , just add -delete at the end to delete them right away i.e
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +10 -type f -delete

Answer (score 16):

this should work for you

`find /path -mmin +59 -type f -exec rm -fv {} \;`

Comment: What is the trailing backslash for?

Comment: @Matt The trailing backslash before semicolon is used because `;` is one of the list operators for separating shell commands and that's why needs to be escaped.